# Flink task manager crashes on startup with: There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue

Tags: docker, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm using Flink 1.16.0 and the Docker Compose config file as below. My task manager crashes as soon as I start the containers with `docker compose up` when I set `taskmanager.memory.process.size: 32gb` in the `FLIINK_PROPERTIES`. The error is:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000003ab000000, 18605932544, 0) failed; error='Not enough space' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 18605932544 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /opt/flink/hs_err_pid1.log
```

The thing I don't understand is that it does not crash on my local machine which has 16Gb memory. It only crashes on the production server that has 64Gb memory.

On the production server it does work with `taskmanager.memory.process.size: 29gb` or less.

Production machine:
Docker: Docker Engine - Community 20.10.17.
Docker Compose version: 2.6.0.
OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.9

My `compose.yml` file:

```
services:
  jobmanager:
    image: flink:1.16.0-scala_2.12-java11
    ports:
      - "${FLINK_WEB_PORT}:8081"
    command: jobmanager
    environment:
      - |
        FLINK_PROPERTIES=
        jobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager        
        state.backend: hashmap


  taskmanager:
    image: flink:1.16.0-scala_2.12
    depends_on:
      - jobmanager
    command: taskmanager
    environment:
      - |
        FLINK_PROPERTIES=
        jobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager
        taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 8
        taskmanager.memory.process.size: 32gb
        state.backend: hashmap
```

I have not disabled jemalloc.

Comment: This topic has come up a couple of times in the Flink User mailing list. A good example of that is https://lists.apache.org/thread/q528x1z2lw6s8yzkzkngfzxwb3zkbh0n. A couple of things that are worthwhile to verify:

- Does Flink crash immediately or after a certain period?

- What is the memory usage of Flink and other processes? 

- What type of Flink application/topology are you running? Do you store information in state?

- What memory backend do you use?

Comment: Thanks @MartijnVisser I have updated the question. FYI it crashes immediately. I have included some more information.